# why is rs.Next() skipping column

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

i have been trying to build a GUI which takes the images from the MySQL DB and displays one after each when the next button is clicked, it works fine except it skips one image and displays one after it, i have checked the id of the same row the id is skipped as well so i presume it's a problem mysql connector.

example of the method:

```
public Pair<Integer,Image> image2()throws SQLException
    {
        int id;
        System.out.println("I am in Image");

        try {

            System.out.println(rs);

            boolean anyResults = false;

            if (rs.next())
            {

                anyResults = true;

                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");

                id = rs.getInt("id");

                System.out.println(id);
                System.out.println(blob);
                System.out.println(blob.length());


                InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream(1, blob.length());

                System.out.println(rs.next());
                System.out.println(in);

                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
                System.out.println(image);

                Image image1 = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image,null);


                return new Pair<>(id, image1);

            }
            else if (!anyResults)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
            }


            System.out.println("reached here");


        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

example of the nextButton:

```
public void NextButtomClicked() throws SQLException
    {
        //  this is what i used before =>   Image image1 = sql.image2();

        //Pair<Integer, Image> image1 = sql.image2();

        //Pair<Integer, Image> pair = sql.image2();
        Pair<Integer, Image> pair = sql.image2();

        Image image = pair.getValue();

        list.add(pair.getKey());

        this.imageView.setImage(image);

    }
```

PS. if(rs.Next) works the same way as the while(rs.Next)

Comment: Probably because of System.out.println(rs.next()); where you call next again

Comment: See [ResultSet.next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) : _Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position._. `if(rs.next()` will move the cursor. Sane as the call in the print. "_PS. if(rs.Next) works the same way as the while(rs.Next)_" well because you have a `return` statement in that block.

Comment: thank you for your comments), @VeselinDavidov yes you were right i did that because i wanted to get the return value of rs.next i did not know that will move it forward very silly of me((, if you add your comment to an answer i will put that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.out.println(rs.next());  jump the row

Try:

```
public Pair<Integer,Image> image2()throws SQLException
{
    int id;
    System.out.println("I am in Image");

    try {

        System.out.println(rs);

        boolean anyResults = false;

        boolean hasNext = rs.next();


        if (hasNext )
        {

            anyResults = true;

            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");

            id = rs.getInt("id");

            System.out.println(id);
            System.out.println(blob);
            System.out.println(blob.length());


            InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream(1, blob.length());

            System.out.println(hasNext );
            System.out.println(in);

            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
            System.out.println(image);

            Image image1 = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image,null);


            return new Pair<>(id, image1);

        }
        else if (!anyResults)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
        }


        System.out.println("reached here");


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: HI sorry to disturb you but if it is ok for you could you please upvote this post since it was put on [hold] for some reason because some people thought it is off topic, thank you!)